# Laravel resource or alias options to display (custom) url

Tags: php, laravel

How can I display `my.site/agents` when agent really is a User?

I have a resource Users, which contains the property 'is_agent' and has extra info if the user is an agent.

I would like to notify the user of the difference when handling either of the 2 by displaying a `my.url/users` or `my.url/agents` depending on the case.

So maybe there is an option to do something along the lines of `Route::resource('users' as 'agents', UserController::class)` in web.php?

I'm really open to suggestions here.

To be honest, I'm not sure I know the right name for what I'm trying to achieve. Even though I've gone through many a website, I came up short. Tried to search for what I reckon to be an alias, also 'as' etc but no cigar.

Comment: You could just create the routes manually, and map them as needed

Comment: Never did this, but can't you just make the controller aware of and then register it on both routes? Or even better create a second controller, the specialization, and extend it from the more generic one. Then put both on their appropriate routes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what are you looking for but you can create two routes to the same controller and execute different logics:

```
Route::resource('users', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('users.index');
Route::resource('agents', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('agents.index');
```

and in the controller you can do something like this:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if (Route::currentRouteName() === 'agents.index') {
            // Handle agent

            return view('agents.index');
        }

        // Handle user

        return view('users.index');
    }
}
```